# Chrome on iOS 8 useragent no longer include crIOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

Has anyone else noticed?  Latest Chrome for iOS on iPhone with 8.1.2, the userAgent no longer has the crIOS string in it.  Not sure why they got rid of it.  It doesn't have "Mobile" in the string anymore either.  I guess that's why one should not rely on userAgent...
The userAgent I am seeing in Javascript is:

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10

Where did crIOS go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered the answer just before posting.  Apparently I'd clicked, some time ago, on this tab of Chrome and selected to "view the desktop version".  This changes the userAgent to no longer indicate it is a mobile IOS version of the browser.  The option was greyed out, though.  I wasn't sure how to go back to the "Mobile" version.  I found this URL:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2664994?hl=en&topic=2365160&ctx=topic

The paragraph labeled: "Why can’t I go back to viewing mobile websites after enabling “Request Desktop Site”?" has the answer to this question.

Rather than making you go there yourself, it says that once you go to desktop mode on a particular tab it will remain set that way forever.  To go back to a mobile view, you must close the tab and reopen a new one.  New tabs default to the mobile userAgent/view.

Mystery solved.

Comment: nice answer on your own :P