# Detect Chrome iPhone 6+

Tags: jquery, ios, user-agent, detect, iphone-6-plus

I used to use:

```
(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') > -1 && (/Chrome\/[.0-9]*/).test(window.navigator.userAgent)) || navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS');
```

to detect Chrome on iOS devices, but it appears the user agent on Chrome for the 6+ is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10 (000578)

I've also used [device.js](https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js) in the past to add the class "mobile" to the HTML tag. Seems neither method works now. Any idea how I can detect Chrome on iPhone 6+?

Comment: `window.hasOwnProperty("chrome")` ?

Comment: thanks. tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: `/(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X)/.test(window.navigator.userAgent) && window.navigator.vendor === "Google Inc."` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome on iOS 8 useragent no longer include crIOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906965/chrome-on-ios-8-useragent-no-longer-include-crios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason my user agent was incorrect. I believe it may have been because I previously invoked the Firebug Lite bookmarklet. The correct user agent is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/40.0.2214.73 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4 (000582)

Now this detector works:

```
(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') > -1 && (/Chrome\/[.0-9]*/).test(window.navigator.userAgent)) || navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS');
```